# On local group rings

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, modules, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field of characteristic $p$. Suppose that the ring $k[G]$ is local. How this implies that G is a p-group?

In fact, there are different proofs as in the answers below. But, I'm confused with the hint that rised in the exercise ( page 54) given in ( library.msri.org/books/Book51/files/02iyengar.pdf).

Since all maximal ideals are prime, the nilradical $nil(k[G])$ is contained in the Jacobson radical $J(k[G])$. Since $k[G]$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, it is a left-Artinian ring. So all prime ideals are maximal and then  $nil(k[G])=J(k[G])$. However, I'm not sure how to use this hint to prove that $G$ is a $p$-group.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have given an answer that uses the hint (and one that doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

It seems a more elementary approach will work.  We use two standard observations for any finite subgroup $H$ of $G$:

1. When the order $n$ of $H$ is invertible in $k$, then $e=n^{-1}\sum_{h\in H}h$ is an idempotent; and
2. $he=e$ for any $h\in H$

Now pick a nonidentity element $x'$ of $G$ and consider $H'=\langle x'\rangle$.  If $|H'|$ is not a power of $p$, then we can find a nonidentity element of $H'$ with order coprime to $p$. Call this element $x$ and the subgroup it generates $H$.  We've guaranteed the order $n$ of $x$ (and $H$) is invertible in $k$ to satisfy 2 above.

Considering that $R[G]$ is local, it only has trivial idempotents, and the idempotent from 1 above is nonzero, so $e=1$. But multiplying both sides of $e=1$ with $x$, with 2 above we have $x=xe=e=1$.  This is a contradiction, however, since $1_G$ and $x$ are linearly independent elements in $k[G]$.

Thus the only possible order for an element in $G$ is a power of $p$.

---

You may find it interesting to know that it is unnecessary to assume $G$ is finite.

Theorem 1 of

> Renault, G. “Sur les anneaux de groupes.” CR Acad. Sci. Paris Sr. AB 273 (1971): A84-A87.

shows that $G$ is a $p$-group for some $p$ when $R[G]$ is local.  You can find [an English translation here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08586).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But how the fact $nil(k[G])=J(k[G])$ is used here.

Comment: @NohaRaghit I have no idea. It seems irrelevant to me but possibly someone had an ingenious answer based on it.  In fact you do not _need_ that, because it’s true even when $G$ is infinite and so the ring isn’t Artinian.

Comment: @LukasHeger I'd like to see that, but I don't understand how the equality of the hom groups is related to $G$ being a p-group.  Must be something representation theorists recognize immediately.  Honestly I would have included Renault's justification, but I found it too sketchy (he only used about two lines to justify this fact). Maybe it looks more complicated because he's proving all the other points too.

Comment: @rschwieb the equality of Hom groups I wrote works independently from $G$ being a $p$ group. The critical point is that if $G$ is _not_ a $p$-group, we can find a (cyclic) subgroup $H$ such that there's a nontrivial irreducible representaion of $H$ over $k$. That's the part that fails for $p$-groups.The equality of Homs business let's us show that this implies that $k[G]$ cannot be local, because local rings have just one isomorphism class of simple modules, here the trivial rep.

Comment: @LukasHeger Thank you for the explanation so far. Still need more, though, because it's still pretty greek to me! Why does that equality mean there's more than one isoclass?

Comment: @rschwieb Because that equality shows that the trivial representation is not a submodule of the $W$ we constructed (as the invariants are zero). But every nonzero module has simple submodule, so there must be some other isoclass of simple modules.

Comment: @LukasHeger _every nonzero module has a simple submodule_ when $G$ is finite, I agree.  Thank you for taking the time to explain. If my feedback is useful, I would say that this is probably elegant (and so in some sense elementary) to a representation theorist, but it is quite complicated to a humble ring theorist such as myself.  Renault's arguments are elementary (in the sense of only talking about ring elements an operations) almost to a fault.  Also his line has the benefit of not depending on $G$ being finite. He probably could have explained it better, though... he was a little vague.

Comment: @rschwieb oh, you're right, my proof only works for finite groups, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the correction

Comment: so it's not your fault for not understanding, the argument was just not complete.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a completely different proof. It uses the fact that the Jacobson radical is nilpotent and maximal, and the residue ring is a division ring.

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $k$ have characteristic $p$, and suppose that $kG$ is local. Thus $I=J(kG)$ is nilpotent and maximal, and $kG/I$ has no zero divisors.

Let $q\neq p$ be a prime and suppose that $x\in G$ has order $q$. Then $x^q-1=0$ in $kG$. Since $kG/I$ is a division ring, and $x^q-1=(x-1)(x^{q-1}+\cdots+x+1)$, one of those factors is zero in $kG/I$, i.e., lies in $I$. If $x-1$ lies in $I$ then (as $I$ is nilpotent) some sufficiently large power $(x-1)^{p^i}=x^{p^i}-1$ is zero, which is obviously false. Thus the second term lies in $I$.

Raise $\alpha=x^{q-1}+x^{q-2}+\cdots+x+1$ to the $p$th power:
$$(x^{q-1}+x^{q-2}+\cdots+x+1)^p=x^{p(q-1)}+x^{p(q-2)}+\cdots+x^p+1.$$
Since $q$ is a prime, the set $\{pi\mid 1\leq i\leq q-1\}$ is equal to $\{i\mid 1\leq i\leq q-1\}$ modulo $q$. Thus $\alpha^p=\alpha$, so clearly this is not nilpotent either. This is a contradiction.

Comment: you need to be slightly careful with prime ideals in the noncommutative setting. While every maximal ideal is indeed prime, the definition of a prime ideal is not what you might think it is.

Comment: I've altered the words in the proof, which remains the same, to remove references to primeness. In Iyengar's notes, which the OP has taken this from, it is pointed out that $kG/I$ is a division ring, which is all I am using.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven you're right, we were probably being pedantic

Comment: Oh yes, $I$ would be absolutely prime in this case, wouldn't it :). This is probably what Iyengar was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elementary proof. Since $kG$ is local, there is a unique simple $kG$-module, which is necessarily the trivial module. Thus $kG$ is a *polytrivial* module, i.e., a module all of whose composition factors are trivial.

Now take any composition series for $kG$. By choosing an obvious basis such that the $i$th element generates the $i$th submodule of this series, the elements of $G$ are expressible as triangular matrices. Furthermore, since the composition factors are trivial, the diagonal entries of these matrices are $1$.

Finally, the set of upper unitriangular matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_n(q)$ ($q$ a power of $p$) is a $p$-group, and the same holds for $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$, and we are done.

Comment: @rschwieb Added that $q$ is some power of $p$. It's very easy to see that the unitriangular matrices over a finite field is a $p$-group. For infinite fields one needs to actually write something down rather than just count matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. But there are no finite fields in sight other than the prime subfield... it's enough that it holds for the prime subfield, yes?  Maybe the generality is distracting me.

Comment: Or there's no implication. The claim simply is that the unitriangular matrices over a field characteristic $p$ forms a p-group.  Interesting representational viewpoint.

Comment: @rschwieb If $k=\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ then each matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ lies in some $\mathrm{GL}_n(q)$, so the finite case is enough. For other infinite fields, I think you actually have to take a $p$th power and see that the entries on the leading superdiagonal are multiplied by $p$ to obtain the result. You might be able to use a compactness argument or some other model-theoretic trickery to see it? Maybe the fact that all algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you very much for your answer. But it is required for me to use the fact $nil(k[G])=J(k[G])$.

Comment: @rschwieb I think you can use model theory. The result holds for the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, so it holds for some algebraic closure. But every upper unitriangular matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ satisfies $M^r=I$, where $r$ is any power of $p$ greater than $n$. This yields a bunch of polynomial equations in the entries of the matrix, which are arbitrary elements of $k$. This is a first-order statement.

Comment: @NohaRaghit Doesn't that imply a single simple module?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Without the ring being local, it doesn't, no.  And if the ring is local it follows immediately there's a single simple module without detouring through the coincidence of the radicals.  It's certainly not clear (to me) at this point what the contribution of this hint is (if that's what it is.)

Comment: @rschwieb You are right, I obviously was just being ridiculous. No idea how it helps, because the statement $J(kG)=nil(kG)$ holds for all finite groups, not just $p$-groups. So I think you cannot use the 'hint'.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven
  Yes, I agree with you. So I'm confused with this hint that rised in this exercise ( page 54) http://library.msri.org/books/Book51/files/02iyengar.pdf

Comment: @DavidA.Craven using model theory to show that upper unitriangular matrices have $p$-power order seems overkill. Let $U$ be upper unitriangular. By Caley-Hamilaton, we have that the minimal polynomial divides $(X-1)^n$. Now take $m$ such that $p^m\geq n$. Then we get that $(X-1)^n$ divides $(X-1)^{p^m}=X^{p^m}-1$ and we are done.

Comment: @LukasHeger I was being silly, of course, because you can simply raise the matrix to the $p$th power and clear the superdiagonal. That's a very simple calculation, and far easier than proving the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. But thanks for pointing that out, I'd never proved it that way, I always just did the short calculation.

Comment: @NohaRaghit Context like where you got the exercise from is very useful information and really should have been included in the original question from the start. Can you please edit it in?

Answer (score 2):

We prove the statement by contradiction. Let $x \in G$ whose order is not a power of $p$. Let $H=\langle x \rangle$. Then $H$ has an irreducible nontrivial representation $V$ over $k$. (Note: this is wrong if the order of $x$ is a power of $p$, because then the only irreducible representation is the trivial one.) Consider the co-induced representation $W:=\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k[G],V)$. This is a representation of $G$. We compute its invariants. Because we used the co-induced representation (and not the induced one) we have without any assumptions regardings the finiteness of $[G:H]$ via **Shapiro's lemma** [note: or just the Tensor-Hom adjunction, see below]

$$W^G=H^0(G,W)=H^0(H,V)=V^H=0$$

So we have found a nontrivial representation with trivial invariants.

But if $k[G]$ is local, then the only left maximal ideal is the augmentation ideal, so every irreducible representation is trivial, because every such representation is isomorphic $k[G]/\mathfrak{m}$ for a left maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

But every nontrivial representation has a irreducible subrepresentation, so if $k[G]$ is local, then $W^G \neq 0$ for all nonzero $k[G]$-modules $W$.

---

If you don't want to cite a result from group cohomology, here's an elementary proof of the equality $$\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k[G],V)^G=V^H$$ for any $k[H]$-module $V$. Let $k$ denote the trivial $k[H]$-module or $k[G]$-module, respectively. Then we have
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k[G],V)^G=\mathrm{Hom}_{k[G]}(k,\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k[G],V))=\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k \otimes_{k[G]} k[G],V)$$
$$=\mathrm{Hom}_{k[H]}(k,V)=V^H$$

Comment: +1 for another interesting representation theory technique!